# Vimperator and Ctrl+K 

Tags: firefox, vimperator

This is related to my other question about [copy/pasting in Vimperator](https://superuser.com/questions/12681).

In normal Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> gives the focus to the search bar.

How can I do this in Vimperator?

The weird thing is that it doesn't work even in `-- PASS THROUGH --` mode. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works in pass through, why is it that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> doesn't?

Is there a fix or a patch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, awesome job figuring out wildoptions

That said, I'd just add that if you just hit <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>t</kbd> it should take you to the command box with the pre-filled command **:open** or **:tabopen** respectively. You could type some text and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to look at auto-complete options for that text.

---

Also if you ever want to see your search bar for whatever reason:

```
:set go+=T
```

Now you should have your entire toolbar, but to access the searchbox I use:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> -> <kbd>Tab</kbd>

  OR
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> -> <kbd>Tab</kbd>

To get rid of the unsightly toolbar just use:

```
:set go-=T
```

---

Also:
 you could open up searchoptions via:

```
:dia searchengines
```

and set the keywords for each search engine. For eg: Google -> g, Yahoo -> y, etc.

Now when you need to search just hit <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>t</kbd> and follow up the command with g hello as in:

```
:open g hello
```

to open a google search page for the word hello

Answer (score 6):

I knew :open behaves essentially like a google search box, but what bothered me was the absence of the auto-suggestions list.

Well, it turns out that `set wildoptions=auto` turns it on, so with that in mind, here's my workaround:

```
set wildoptions=auto

noremap <C-k> :open 
inoremap <C-k> <Esc>:open 
cnoremap <C-k> <Esc>:open
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works well for me, a variant on facepalmd's suggestion :

```
:set go+=T                      # Turns on the address bar, which I don't mind
:noremap <C-k> <A-d><Tab>       # maps Ctrl-K to Alt-D + Tab
```

Answer (score 1):

F6 focuses the address bar for me. I use the following software.

- Vimperator 2.3.1
- Firefox 3.6.10
- Mac OS X 10.5

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/vimperator/2008-May/001544.html), Firefox performs unexpected behavior when pressing Ctrl+k, and vimperator cannot handle it. An alternative is to search like so:

```
:o [engine] [search terms]
```

For instance, to search *google* for *SuperUser*, the command would be

```
:o google SuperUser
```

Comment: The problem with seraching from the :open command is that you don't get the auto suggestions and other goodies (like automatically showing calculator results)

Comment: The thread I linked shows a workaround

Answer (score -1):

Try pressing F6.  F6 focusses the address bar when vimperator is active.

Comment: won't work even in pass through

Comment: Vimperator hides the address bar by default. F6 is unmapped.

Comment: Wrong.  F6 highlights the address bar in Vimperator.

Comment: Right. F6 does nothing on default Vimperator config.

Comment: My config is default. Pressing it once does nothing. A second press highlights the address bar (not the one you type in).